# How to Create a Draggable Line in HTML5 Canvas using ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, html5-canvas

How to drag lines in canvas?

I am able to add lines in canvas using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559248/how-to-create-a-draggable-line-in-html5-canvas).

In this, [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559248/how-to-create-a-draggable-line-in-html5-canvas) line drag is working but when I use it in the ionic app it's not working.

> here my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild('canvasDraw', { static: false }) canvas: ElementRef;

  canvasElement: any;
  lines: any[];
  isDown: boolean = false;
  startX: number;
  startY: number;
  nearest: any;
  offsetX: any;
  offsetY: any;

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    }, 1000)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    // canvas lets
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvasDraw");

    // line lets
    // let this.nearest;
    this.lines = [];
    this.lines.push({ x0: 75, y0: 25, x1: 125, y1: 25 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 75, y0: 100, x1: 125, y1: 100 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 50, y0: 35, x1: 50, y1: 85 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 150, y0: 35, x1: 150, y1: 85 });

    this.draw();
  }

  reOffset() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvasDraw");
    let BB = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.offsetX = BB.left;
    this.offsetY = BB.top;
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
  }

  // select the this.nearest line to the mouse
  closestLine(mx, my) {
    let dist = 100000000;
    let index, pt;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lines.length; i++) {
      //
      let xy = this.closestXY(this.lines[i], mx, my);
      //
      let dx = mx - xy.x;
      let dy = my - xy.y;
      let thisDist = dx * dx + dy * dy;
      if (thisDist < dist) {
        dist = thisDist;
        pt = xy;
        index = i;
      }
    }
    let line = this.lines[index];
    return ({ pt: pt, line: line, originalLine: { x0: line.x0, y0: line.y0, x1: line.x1, y1: line.y1 } });
  }

  // linear interpolation -- needed in setClosestLine()
  lerp(a, b, x) {
    return (a + x * (b - a));
  }

  // find closest XY on line to mouse XY
  closestXY(line, mx, my) {
    let x0 = line.x0;
    let y0 = line.y0;
    let x1 = line.x1;
    let y1 = line.y1;
    let dx = x1 - x0;
    let dy = y1 - y0;
    let t = ((mx - x0) * dx + (my - y0) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);
    t = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, t));
    let x = this.lerp(x0, x1, t);
    let y = this.lerp(y0, y1, t);
    return ({ x: x, y: y });
  }

  // draw the scene
  draw() {
    let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    let cw = this.canvasElement.width;
    let ch = this.canvasElement.height;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    // draw all lines at their current positions
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lines.length; i++) {
      this.drawLine(this.lines[i], 'black');
    }
    // draw markers if a line is being dragged
    if (this.nearest) {
      // point on line this.nearest to mouse
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.nearest.pt.x, this.nearest.pt.y, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
      ctx.stroke();
      // marker for original line before dragging
      this.drawLine(this.nearest.originalLine, 'red');
      // hightlight the line as its dragged
      this.drawLine(this.nearest.line, 'red');
    }
  }

  drawLine(line, color) {
    let ctx = this.canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(line.x0, line.y0);
    ctx.lineTo(line.x1, line.y1);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  handleMouseDown(e: { preventDefault: () => void; stopPropagation: () => void; clientX: number; clientY: number; }) {
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // mouse position
    this.startX = e.clientX - this.offsetX;
    this.startY = e.clientY - this.offsetY;
    // find this.nearest line to mouse
    this.nearest = this.closestLine(this.startX, this.startY);
    this.draw();
    // set dragging flag
    this.isDown = true;
  }

  handleMouseUpOut(e) {
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // clear dragging flag
    this.isDown = false;
    this.nearest = null;
    this.draw();
  }

  handleMouseMove(e) {
    if (!this.isDown) { return; }
    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    // mouse position
    const mouseX = e.clientX - this.offsetX;
    const mouseY = e.clientY - this.offsetY;
    // calc how far mouse has moved since last mousemove event
    let dx = mouseX - this.startX;
    let dy = mouseY - this.startY;
    this.startX = mouseX;
    this.startY = mouseY;
    // change this.nearest line vertices by distance moved
    let line = this.nearest.line;
    line.x0 += dx;
    line.y0 += dy;
    line.x1 += dx;
    line.y1 += dy;
    // redraw
    this.draw();
  }

}
```

> here my HTML file

```
<canvas #canvasDraw width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

I tried to like this but looks like it's not working

```
<canvas #canvasDraw width=300 height=300 (mousedown)="handleMouseDown($event)" (mousemove)="handleMouseMove($event)"
    (mouseup)="handleMouseUpOut($event)" (mouseout)="handleMouseUpOut($event)"></canvas>
```

Comment: Few things i can see right of the bat #canvasDraw is not retrieveable by getDocumentById, instead use the viewchild you already have, also when adding  to the DOM consider using renderer2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to ensure the offsets are set with this method: reOffset().
In the code you shared above you are not using that method at all and the code relies on offsets to be set correctly.

This method should be called once the view is fully initialized and even ngAfterViewInit() is not going to help capture actual offsets unfortunately since Ionic's header won't be fully initialized.

So I used requestAnimationFrame trick to ensure the offsets are set correctly (you could use Promise.resolve also or play with setTimeout):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
    this.lines = [];
    this.lines.push({ x0: 75, y0: 25, x1: 125, y1: 25 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 75, y0: 100, x1: 125, y1: 100 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 50, y0: 35, x1: 50, y1: 85 });
    this.lines.push({ x0: 150, y0: 35, x1: 150, y1: 85 });
    this.draw();
    //this.reOffset();
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
      this.reOffset()
    })
  }
```

Working version here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-twdvkm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank u for your answer, It's working in the web but it's not working on the device. What to do for the touch event?

Comment: This is a separate issue - can you create a separate question?